# Bokeh not using all available space

Tags: python, bokeh

I've made a visualization using Bokeh and tested it with my iMac 27 inches and everything was fine:

[image]

However, when working on my notebook, 15 inches, I've noticed that things become messy:

[image]

As can be seen by the histogram in the bottom, there is more available space to the left, where this whole "box" with the black image and classifiers should be. I'm not sure why this is happening and how to fix it.

The code is not small, but these are the sizes of my figures and the layout used:

```
# black square
pi = figure(plot_width=230, plot_height=160)
# Left histogram
pv = figure(plot_height=380, plot_width=235)
# Tab
p = figure(plot_width=640, plot_height=480)
# Bottom histogram
ph = figure(plot_width=880, plot_height=200

# Layout
l = column(
    row(column(tabs, t_slider),
        column(pi, pv)
       ), 
    ph)
curdoc().add_root(l)
```

I expected the slide+tabs and black square+histogram to be in two columns, side by side, as it was when using a bigger display. I thought that Bokeh wasn't using all available space due to some css configuration. However, from the bottom histogram is possible to see that there is space to put this second box in the appropriated position.

Comment: You need a responsive layout. As discussed in the answer, there are several sizing modes you could try for the layout. Here's the official docs: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/layouts.html#bokeh.models.layouts.LayoutDOM.sizing_mode

Comment: I tried all of the them and the result is the same, @amanb.

Comment: What version of bokeh are you using?

Comment: @amanb, '1.1.0dev3'

Comment: This could be related to an Open issue with that version of Bokeh: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/8638. There is a workaround suggested, you may try that.

Comment: Thank you for the information. @amanb. I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a responsive layout. I belive this should work:

```
from bokeh.layouts import layout

l = layout(
    [
        [tabs, t_slider, pi, pv],
        [ph]
    ],
    sizing_mode="stretch_both"
)
```

If you want to maintain the aspect ratio you could use `sizing_mode="scale_both"`.

More info about the different `sizing_mode` options are in the documentation:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/layouts.html#bokeh.models.layouts.LayoutDOM.sizing_mode

Comment: I have tried all the options and the result is still the same. Also, using `layout` instead of a combination `column` and `row` changes the layout.